# How to do division with bc (bench calculator) and obtain fractional results?

Tags: linux, bc

```
bc
1/2
0

5/3
1

10/3
3
```

When a fraction is entered into `bc`, the result is truncated to an integer. How can this behavior be avoided, such that the output of a division operation is a real number?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try something like `scale=2`

From the [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC14):

> scale ( expression )
>
> The value of the scale function is the number of digits after the
>   decimal point in the expression.

By default, the scale is 0, so no digits after the decimal are shown.

Answer (score 22):

Just invoke `bc` with the `-l` argument:

```
bc -l
```

Example:

```
$ bc -l
1/2
.50000000000000000000
5/3
1.66666666666666666666
10/3
3.33333333333333333333
```

Comment: This is useful when using `bc` without entering it, e.g. `bc -l <<< 2/4`

Comment: `-l` is my new favorite flag

Answer (score 6):

Use the `scale` special variable to define decimal places:

```
scale=4
1/2
.5000
```

Comment: Thanks, you both had the right answer, and at essentially the same time.